# Custom ui form with Magento core_config_data table

Tags: magento2, ui-form, system-config, core-config-data

I was required to manage custom core_config_data (system config) values with a separate form from the Magento Admin side. How I can retrieve the values saved in the table with the data provider?

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->scopeConfig->getValue('general/locale/timezone', ScopeInterface::SCOPE_WEBSITE);
```

where `general/locale/timezone` is the config path to adapt and `scopeConfig` is an instance of `Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;`

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking custom core_config_data table value? if Yes then I would suggest two options:

1. Using defining the model and call modelFatory in block you can get custom table data:

> ```
> public function __construct(
>     Context $context,
>     \Namespace\Module\Model\ModuleFactory $modelFactory,
>
>     array $data = array()
> ) {
>     $this->_modelFactory = $modelFactory;
>     parent::__construct($context, $data);
> }
> ```

You can get collection by factory methods:

```
public function getCollection(){

    return $this->_modelFactory->create()->getCollection();

}
```

Reference website: https://magefan.com/blog/load-data-from--magento-2-database

2. Without a Model, you can use a direct connection object and gettable data using a select query.

> ```
> <?php
>
> namespace Venodr\ModuleName\Model;
>
> use Magento\Framework\EntityManager\MetadataPool;
> use Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Operation\ExtensionInterface;
>
> class CustomData
> {
>     protected $connection;
>
>     public function __construct(
>         \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource
>     )
>     {
>         $this->connection = $resource->getConnection();
>     }
>
>     public function getQueryData()
>     { 
>         $query = $this->connection->fetchAll("SELECT * FROM custom_core_config_data");
>         return $query;
>     }
> }
> ```

Please let me know if this will not help.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Unfortunately, it  does not meet my requirement. I just need create a magento2 admin ui form with core_config_data table values to set up a custom settings page. However, I was managed it with custom dataprovider with Magento\Config\Model\ResourceModel\Config\Data\CollectionFactory